# Использование одной и той же функции в разных файлах

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Всем привет. Не очень давно начал изучать Java в Android Studio, создавая приложение на телефон. И столкнулся с такой проблемой - основная activity (activity_main у меня зовется) стремительно набирает оборот (много кода в этом файле). Можно ли как-то вынести, например, все, связанное с регистрацией из activity_main в один файл, связанное с навигацией - в другой, связанное еще с чем-то - в третий?

Comment: Почитайте о фрагментах. Разделяйте код по логике на фрагменты и выносите их. Кроме того, можно организовать иерархию activity, так чтобы каждый "слой" отвечал за определенную функциональность.

Comment: активити - контроллер виджетов. Все, что она должна делать - реагировать на действия пользователя (определить нажатие кнопки, получить введенный текст и тп), все остальное должны выполнять другие классы - не надо писать весь код (бизнес-логику, взаимодействие с хранилищем и тп) в акивити, все это нужно выносить в другие классы. Подробнее [смотрите этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/652130/177345)

Comment: Простите, а где-то можно пример увидеть? Потому что я не понимаю как это правильно реализовать, какие модификаторы дописывать и куда... Я сишник по своей натуре, а здесь еще ноль :)

Comment: пример ... У Google есть [приложение-пример IOSched](https://github.com/google/iosched/tree/master/lib/src/main)  в котором они демонстрируют лучшие практики (по их мнению). Вообще на Github можно без особого труда найти проект любой сложности и использовать его в качестве примера кода.

Comment: Для старта, вам очень поможет продвинуться это видеоуроки https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужно как то упорядочить и разбить activity_main.xml 
Вы можете разбить разметку на компоненты который не завязаны друг на друге в разные layout.xml  , а в activity_main сделать

```
<include layout="@layout/content_fz_main" />
```

Так же можно посмотреть в сторону фрагментов.

Comment: Не-не, меня разбиение классов больше волнует)

Comment: ну тогда Fragment ваш выбор.